# Best way to deal with multiple modals with map data in nextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, state, setstate

Hi I try to use map data with modals. I set state for all modal but after I use map data array object. I have problems the modals show duplicated . Sorry I think my explanation does't clear so I will show you my code below

for example this is my object

```
const obj = [
  {
    id:1
    name:"test"
  },
  {
    id:2
    name:"test2"
  },
  {
    id:3
    name:"test3"
  }
]
```

this is  my Modal components ( this just for an example modal code I didn't put all className)

```
const Modal = ({ children, show = false }) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(show);
  useEffect(() => {
    setShowModal(show);
  }, [show]);

  return showModal ? (
      <div>
        <div className="text-xl">title</div>
        {children}
      </div>
  ) : null;
};
```

as you see in my Modal component I send `props show` for check if it's true show modal else not show

Here is my listModal in this component when I click each card I want modal show each card by id

```
const ListModal = ({}) => {
  const [showEditModal, setShowEditModal] = useState(false);

  return obj.map((list) => {
    return (
      <>
        <Card key={list.id} onClick={() => setShowEditModal(true)}>
          <Modal show={showEditModal}>{list.id}</Modal>
        </Card>
      </>
    );
  });
};

export default ListModal;
```

the problem is in {list.id} in must return in 1,2,3, but it's all return 1 and I try to inspect element and I set css styled display:none into modal element and I saw {list.id} = 2 that's mean all modal is show but it all stack at same place any idea how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use id in `setShowEditModal()` to match the modal.

Comment: stil didnt get it any example ?

Comment: you mean in card when I click setShowEditModal(list.id) ? and in modal how do I check by id

Comment: Pass a prop id to a modal with value list.id, and then when you render, use:
showModal (which will be id ) == id (prop from modal). And you don't have to use state here, just go directly from props

Comment: @Akw Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/r04300ojnp) example.